# Difference between srIvidyA upAsanA in Vedanta and in Tantra?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, tantra, agamas, sri-vidya

Recently I came to know from one of my friend that srIvidyA upAsanA is also done in Vedanta. While I am aware that srIvidyA is Tantrik upAsanA. I was unaware of Vedantic one. Also as far as I know, srIvidyA upAsanA is fruitful when done by both i.e. husband and wife. So how does Vedanta which promotes Sanyasism, do upAsanA of srIvidyA ?

Comment: @Partha I am not aware of Kaulopanishad. But yeah I am aware of Kaula Tantra.

Comment: Never heard of Srividya in vedanta. As far as I know, it is part of tantra.

Answer (score 2):

In the worship of Sri-Vidya, there are three ways(Matas)-- Samaya-mata, Kaula-mata and Mishra-mata.

In the commentary of the Saundaryalahari (sloka 31), Lakshmidhara writes

> The graceful God Pasupati has recommended different Tantras for the four main and mixed varnas. These Tantras are NOT for the brahmins following the Vedas.**For the followers of the Vedas,Lord Pasupati has composed 'Suva-Aagama-Tantra-panchaka'. Vasishtha,Sanaka,Suka, Sananda and Sanatkumar--these five munis have followed this path known as the 'Samaya-aachaara'.**

Sri Panchanana Tarkaratna writes in this regard

> **Samayachara involves only Manasa-upaasana or Internal Worship.There is no provision for external worship.**

So the Samayacharis do not have any purascharana, japa, homa or external pujavidhi.

There is no restriction on the Kaulaachari-s also.Lakshmidhara opines that yogis who concentrate on the sushumna are the real kaulas. However, some samayaacharies do not accept the Kaulaachaara as a path to be followed by the Vedic brahmins.

**So to conclude, the brahmacharins and sannyasins are allowed to do Sri-Vidya sadhana, but the path is not purely a Vedantic one.**, even though we get mention of the 'Kaula-Upanishad' and 'Bhavana-Upanishad'.

According to some views, Sri Adi Shankaracharya Himself did practise Sri Vidya Upasana by the way.

Reference: Sastramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das,RMIC, Vol.1, chapter 12.

Comment: give your e mail